# Can't install on an Asus EEE PC 900 due to udev timeout error

Tags: installation, usb, udev

I have an ASUS EEE PC 900. I am trying to install using a bootable USB drive. I have tried installing Ubuntu 11.10 and 10.04 as well as Lubuntu 11.10. Every time a get a repeating message to the effect of

```
udevd[100]: timeout: killing '/sbin/blkid -o udev -p /dev/sdc' [252]
```

followed by a message saying that process was killed and then nothing.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to remove external sdcard.
2. Try to insert flash drive in other usb slot.
3. Try to user other usb drive.

Way 1. and 2. work for me.